# Import javax.namespace in Android

Tags: android, import, namespaces, apache-axis

I am trying to import certain classes like

```
javax.namespace.QName
```

and
    org.apache.axis2.*

but I am unable to use these classes in my program. I actually got this code after converting a wsdl file into java using wsdl2java. Can anyone help me  which libraries I need to use in order to get support for these classes. Also I shall be greatly thankful to you if someone can guide me about how can I add external libraries in eclipse in my Android project.

Looking forward to some useful responses. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read some stuff about dalvik http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)
Dalvik VM is not JVM, it run different bytecode, so you have to prepare jars by tools/add sources to you project as library. But javax is a Java EE package as I know, and it has a lot of dependencies (could be even incompatible).

For eclipse: 
1) create android project , go to project  properties > Android > check Is Library
2) add library to project (the same way)